# Mule ESB - Retrieve URL HTTP Request from file

Tags: http, mule, esb, raml

I'm using Mule since 1 week. I already managed to connect to a HTTP REST request, using Quartz to trigger the events every tot minutes. My request gives me back an XML or a JSON. Now, I need to do the same but to retrieve the url, to which connect, from a file or a resource, easy to modify if in the future I want to change the url or add another one.
Can someone help me? 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the file connector or the mule requester module. Those will let you pick up a file from your system. Then you can use a MEL expression to use that as the request URL.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! 
If I use a file connector, I read the file and trasform it to a String. Now I need to split it and use the result in the http connector. Can you tell me how can I do this?

Comment: Well, it depends on how complex the contents of the file are. You could try using a mel expression if it's simple. Can you share what said file is going to look like?